# Search capability does not work since upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, gedit, search, text

When I do a search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) in LibreOffice Writer only one letter is accepted, like in some sort of overwrite mode.

The same happens, for example, in gedit.

However a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search from the browser does work.

As a workaround I copy and paste the word I'm looking for in the search window.

PS The problem remains after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10